# How to read Java ArrayList sub-items

Tags: java

Eclipse / Java

```
List<Composicao> itemProdutoLista = compPrecoServico.buscar(Composicao.queryname, parameters);
```

compPrecoServico interface is :

```
@Local
public interface ComposicaoServico extends GenericoServico<Composicao, Integer> {

}
```

GenericoServico has :

```
List<T> buscar(String query, Map<String, ?> parametros);
```

The **queryA** is :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "existingComposicao", query= " SELECT composicao.valortotal,composicao.id FROM Composicao composicao
```

[image]

The question is : How can **read into two different variables** both values (BigDecimal and Integer)

---

- Ive tried without no success :

---

```
Composicao itemProdLista = itemProdutoLista.get(0);
vlUnit = itemProdLista.getResultRS_valortotal();
```

But I get this ERROR in this line : Composicao itemProdLista = itemProdutoLista.get(0);

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to Composicao
```

Comment: Check what you are storing in your `List`.

Comment: Im storing the values regarding the print screen. in [0] and [1] position. I dont know how to read them @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: You must have getters for those values in the `Composicao` class...?

Comment: I have the getters in Composicao

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question when you editorialize your code and only show the most narrow snippets of what's going on.  If you can post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem we can run it ourselves and explain what's happening.

Comment: I just want to read a arrayList sub list item. thats it.

Comment: What ORM are you using?  Hibernate?

Comment: yep. Im using Hibernate

Comment: @Al2x that is obviously not "it", as you are also asking about getting different types out of your "sub list", which generally speaking isn't possible or desirable.  The sample code you've provided, including the trace snippet, is not enough information to understand what you're doing or trying to do.  If you create an example we can run, we can understand what you're doing.  Even better, the simple act of creating an example to share often helps you find the underlying problem yourself.

Comment: Almost certainly the bug is in `queryA function that returns one row list only like that below` but since you've not shown us what that function actually does, we can't hope to tell you where the bug is.

Comment: Man, I need something like this. itemProdutoLista.get(0).get(0) for example only. I know theres no exists get(0).get(0) but it what I need. got it ?

Comment: If the return of your `queryA function` is a `List`, then `get(0)` does exist.  If it's a different type (e.g. a `Composicao`, though we have no idea what that is, since you haven't shown us), then it will have different methods.  The error snippet indicates you're trying to set a `Composicato` to an `ArrayList`, but where, why, or how to fix it are all unclear since you haven't shown us anything.

Comment: updated my post with all the code-behind @dimo414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code doesn't make much sense:

```
List<Composicao> itemProdutoLista = new ArrayList<Composicao>();
itemProdutoLista = ...
```

It's completely useless to create a new ArrayList and assign it to your variable if you reassign another list right after.

Second, your screenshot shows that the list returned by the method is not a `List<Composicao>`, but is in fact a `List<Object[]>` (or a `List<ArrayList>`, given the error message you get from). So you should either fix the function (which, I guess executes a JPA query), or to change the type of your variable to reflect the reality.

To get more help, you should show the code of the function returning the list. This is where the problem is.

EDIT:

Your query is

```
SELECT composicao.valortotal,composicao.id FROM Composicao composicao
```

Such a query doesn't return instances of Composicao, since it selects two fields: `valortotal` and `id`. It would return instances of Composicao if the query was

```
SELECT composicao FROM Composicao composicao
```

If the query is really what you want, the such a query returns a `List<Object[]>`, where each `Object[]` of the list contains two elements: the `valortotal` and the `id`. So your code should be:

```
List<Object[]> itemProdutoLista = ...;
```

Comment: List<T> query(String query, Map<String, ?> parametros); @JB Nizet

Comment: The print-screen has the right values I need to. Im getting error in this line : Composicao itemProdLista = itemProdutoLista.get(0);

Comment: The query you pass is not a query returning Composicao instances. It's a query returning `Object[]` instances. Show us the query. The type of the list should be `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: @NamedQuery(name = "existingComposicao",
    query= " SELECT composicao.valortotal,composicao.id FROM Composicao composicao" @JB Nizet

Comment: Nized. I cant see the full code you provided. what has after List<Object[]> itemProdutoLista = ...;

Comment: List<Object[]> itemProdutoLista = new ArrayList<Object[]>(); Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Composicao> to List<Object[]>

Comment: Read my answer again, and understand that initializing your list with new ArrayList is a waste of time and resources, since you're throwing this new ArrayList away right after. You didn't show what your original code looked like in your answer, so I can't know what you have after `List<Object[]> itemProdutoLista =`. You should have the same thing as what you have right now. What matters is the type of the list, which shouldn't be `List<Composicao>`, but `List<Object[]>`. I have the feeling that you don't understand types and variables and methods. You should learn that much before using JPA.

Comment: I updated my post @JB Nizet. could you take a look on it again please. Your knowledge is very important for my evolution. thanks again.

Comment: The buscar() method declares that it returns a List<Composicao>. But it doesn't. What it actually returns, due to the JPQL query, is a List<Object[]>. So, either you change the query as I showed you in my answer, or you change the buscar method declaration to make it return a List<Object[]>

Comment: thats it. I got it now. thank you so much for sharing your knowledge man :) @JB Nizet

Answer (score 0):

**You have List of lists.**

The **first** element of **itemProdutoLista** is holding a **List**, not a **Composicao object**.

The location of the bug is probably here:

```
 /*function that returns one row list only like that below */
```

Since **Generics** is only evaluated at **compile time**, the method is probably returning the **wrong** thing inside the list.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't he get a compilation error when trying to insert a `List` instead of a `Composicao` object?

Comment: Only if the signature of the called method is using generics as well. In this code you are only preventing that your code insert the "right thing" inside the list.

Comment: He should, unless the method uses raw types instead of generic types.

Answer (score 0):

instanceof to the rescue.
This is not a great idea, but here is some code:

```
List<Object> blammy = new ArrayList<Object>();

BigDecimal kapow = BigDecimal.valueOf(93);
Integer schmarr = Integer.valueOf(10);

blammy.add(kapow);
blammy.add(schmaar);

for (Object current : blammy)
{
     if (current instanceof BigDecimal)
     {
         BigDecimal currentBigDecimal = (BigDecimal)current;

         ... use currentBugDecimal
     }
     else if (current instanceof Integer)
     {
         Integer currentInteger = (Integer)current;

         ... use currentInteger
     }
     else
     {
         ... handle unexpected type.
     }
}
```